# 巨大な CSV から Athena で読めるカラムナー形式に変換したい

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-athena

最終的にやりたいのはタイトル通りです

普通は Athena 上で create 文を叩くと
カラムナーフォーマットのデータをS3に生成してくれるんですが
いまは元データがローカルにある状態です

サイズが 20GB ほどあるので
これを Athena にインポートしてしまうと
スキャンコストでかなり金額がかかってしまいます

なので Athena を使わずにカラムナー形式のファイルをローカルで生成して
S3 において Athena で認識させたいです

node.js に orc を出力できるライブラリがあったので使ってみようと思ったところです

---

https://github.com/corymickelson/norc
この node モジュールを動かしたいのですがどうやって使うのでしょうか

javascript はブラウザで動かすものばかりで node で動かしたことがあまりないので
ピント外れなことかいていたらすみません

```
npm install norc

added 1 package, and audited 7 packages in 2s

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

でモジュール自体はインストールできたんだと思うんですが

test.js

```
import {norc, DataType} from '@npilots/norc'
import {fromPath} from 'fast-csv'
function convert(csv:string, output:string): void {
    const writer = new norc.Writer(output)
    const schema = {x: DataType.SMALLINT, y: DataType.SMALLINT}
    writer.schema(schema)
    fromPath(csv,{ headers: true })
        .on('data', chunk => {
            writer.add({x: chunk.x, y: chunk.y})
        })
        .on('end', () => {
            writer.close()
            // do something with .orc file
        })
}
```

と１つめのサンプルコードをはりつけて実行してみたのですが

```
# node test

import {norc, DataType} from '@npilots/norc'
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

となってしまいます

---

JS やこのモジュールにこだわってるわけではないので
他の言語でもコマンドでも何でもいいので
サイズの小さい Athena で検索できる形に変換する方法があれば知りたいです

サイズが巨大なのでそれなりにパフォーマンスの出る方法だとうれしいです

Comment: Athena のクエリにかかるコストって Tokyo で 5 USD/TB 程度なので、20 GB だと 10 円くらいなのですが、それでも許容できないでしょうか……？ https://aws.amazon.com/jp/athena/pricing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

20 GB 程度であればそのまま Athena の CTAS で変換するのが個人的には便利です。料金もそこまでかからないと思うからです https://aws.amazon.com/jp/athena/pricing/

よりファイルサイズが大きい場合には、ファイル出力時に最初からカラムナ形式にするのがベターでしょう。今回のように CSV ファイルしか与えられていない場合であれば、以下のように変換することもできます。

### CSV -> ORC

CSV 形式のファイルから ORC 形式のファイルに変換したい場合、Apach ORC 公式から提供されているツール群の中に csv-import という名前そのままの CLI ツールが提供されています。

https://orc.apache.org/docs/cpp-tools.html#csv-import

```
$ csv-import --help
Usage: csv-import [-h] [--help]
                  [-d <character>] [--delimiter=<character>]
                  [-s <size>] [--stripe=<size>]
                  [-c <size>] [--block=<size>]
                  [-b <size>] [--batch=<size>]
                  <schema> <input> <output>
Import CSV file into an Orc file using the specified schema.
Compound types are not yet supported.
```

### CSV -> Parquet

CSV 形式から Parquet 形式にする方法はいくつか知られています。たとえば Apache Arrow の Python ライブラリである [pyarrow](https://pypi.org/project/pyarrow/) を使う方法があります。おおまかには以下の流れです。

1. `pyarrow.csv.read_csv` を使って CSV を `pyarrow.Table` のインスタンスとして読み込み https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/csv.html
2. `pyarrow.parquet.write_table` を使って `pyarrow.Table` のインスタンスを Parquet 形式で書きだす https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html

### 元々のエラー

`SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` エラーについては、おそらく、package.json で上手く設定できていないのではと思います。詳しくはドキュメント https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_determining_module_system かこちらの Q&A https://stackoverflow.com/a/59399717/5989200 をご覧ください。