# CSV からAWS Athena array 型のカラムを持つ orc 形式に変換したい

Tags: aws-athena

[巨大な CSV から Athena で読めるカラムナー形式に変換したい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/77430/%E5%B7%A8%E5%A4%A7%E3%81%AA-csv-%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-athena-%E3%81%A7%E8%AA%AD%E3%82%81%E3%82%8B%E3%82%AB%E3%83%A9%E3%83%A0%E3%83%8A%E3%83%BC%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%AB%E5%A4%89%E6%8F%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)
こちらの質問で
https://orc.apache.org/docs/cpp-tools.html#csv-import
このツールを教えていただいたのですがスキーマの与え方がわかりません

---

```
[駅],b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@\x84{a@\x00\x00\x00@\x12\xd5A@'
```

という１行だけのCSVを変換しようとしたところ以下のようなエラーになります

```
csv-import "struct<tags:array<string>,geom:binary>" test.csv test.orc
[2022-02-07 22:17:14] Start importing Orc file...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::runtime_error: array<string> is not supported yet.
zsh: abort      csv-import "struct<tags:array<string>,geometry:binary>" test.csv test.orc
```

https://orc.apache.org/docs/types.html
これを見ると array という記述が存在しないせいみたいなんですが

最終的に以下のような Athena のテーブルでアクセスしたいのですが
Athena 上の array 型になる orc を作るにはどういうスキーマを記述すればいいのでしょうか

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `test`(
  `tags` array<string>, 
  `geometry` binary)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcSerde' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'orc.column.index.access'='false') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://xxxxx'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'has_encrypted_data'='false', 
  'orc.column.index.access'='false', 
  'transient_lastDdlTime'='1560415678')
```

---

list を与えてもダメでした

```
csv-import "struct<tags:list<string>,geom:binary>" test.csv test.orc
[2022-02-08 16:39:42] Start importing Orc file...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: Unknown type list
zsh: abort      csv-import "struct<tags:list<string>,geom:binary>" test.csv test.orc
```

array 自体はキーワードとして認識されるようです

```
csv-import "struct<tags:array,geom:binary>" test.csv test.orc
[2022-02-08 17:49:53] Start importing Orc file...
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::logic_error: Array type must contain exactly one sub type.
zsh: abort      csv-import "struct<tags:array,geom:binary>" test.csv test.orc
```

そもそもCSV側もの与え方も [駅] みたいな書き方でいいのかよくわからないし
Athena コンソール上で array カラムを表示すると [abc, xyz] みたいにでてくるので
試しに [] でくくってみました

https://orc.apache.org/docs/cpp-tools.html#csv-import
このすぐ上の orc-metadata　のところには

```
"struct<boolean1:boolean,byte1:tinyint,short1:smallint,
int1:int,long1:bigint,float1:float,double1:double,bytes1:binary,
string1:string,middle:struct<list:array<struct<int1:int,string1:
string>>>,list:array<struct<int1:int,string1:string>>,map:map<
string,struct<int1:int,string1:string>>>"
```

のような書き方がされてるので array や list でいけるかと思いましたが...

ドキュメントもみあたらず man もないし -h にも説明が出てこないので大人しく pyorc あたり使ってプログラム書くことにします

Answer (score 0):

手元で試していないのですが、ORC で言うところの `list` 型を使えば Athena で言うところの `array` 型に SerDe のタイミングで変換できそうです。